# Trying to get the integral of a complex function

Tags: python, loops, scipy

I have a function in which I am trying to compute the definite integral. However, part of this function uses a map function within it and I am getting a `TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`

Here is my function:

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
def func(a, b, c, d): #a is an array of 4000 elements, b is an array of ten elements, c&d are integers
    n = len(a)
    aver = a.mean()
    stdevn = a.std()
    final = []
    def fn(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d):
        return ((1/n)*sum(map(lambda y: ((1/c) * np.exp(-0.5*((x - y - 0.2*((b-aver)/stdevn)*y)/bandwidth)**2)), a)))

    for i in b:
        total = integrate.quad(fn, a=0, b=100)
        final.append(total)
    return final
```

The result should be an array of length b (10). I am not sure where in the code I have the error. `x` is in the function as it is part of the integration

Traceback:

```
---> 10         total = integrate.quad(fn, a=0, b=100)                             
     11 
     12         final.append(total)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    350     if weight is None:
    351         retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
--> 352                        points)
    353     else:
    354         if points is not None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    461     if points is None:
    462         if infbounds == 0:
--> 463             return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
    464         else:
    465             return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Ever heard about a traceback? Or thought about telling us exactly where the error occurred?

Comment: @hpaulj added the traceback

Comment: did you test `fn`?  `fn(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working solution:

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
def func(a, b, c, d): #a is an array of 4000 elements, b is an array of ten elements, c&d are integers
    n = len(a)
    aver = a.mean()
    stdevn = a.std()
    final = []
   

    for i in b:
        total = integrate.quad(lambda x: x*(inv*sum(map(lambda y: ((1/b) * np.exp(-0.5*((x-y-0.2*((b-aver)/stdevn*x/bandwidth))), clm))), a, b, epsabs = np.inf
        final.append(total)
    return final
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using `scipy.integrate.quad` incorrectly. From the [manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/integrate.html#) page it can be seen that the `quad` function needs the start and end of the interval as arguments. You try to pass two variables (I guess as arguments for your `fn` function?).
Try it similar to `total = integrate.quad(fn, min_interval, max_interval, args=(a, b, c, d))`.
Next time please add a minimal reproducible example. Like this it is more a guessing game.

Comment: Also I would change the `fn` definition from `fn(a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)` to `fn(a, b, c, d)` and then pass `args(0, 100, c, d)` or whatever you need.